# MS Word Macro: How to replace a duplicate paragraph with a new paragraph?

Tags: ms-word

I wonder if you could help me with the following problem.

I have a huge document that contains many duplicate paragraphs. I've found a macro on the Internet that can find them all and delete them:

```
Sub DeleteDuplicateParagraphs()
'PURPOSE: Remove Duplicate Paragraphs Throughout the Entire Word Document
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim p1 As Paragraph
Dim p2 As Paragraph
Dim DupCount As Long

DupCount = 0

For Each p1 In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
  If p1.Range.Text <> vbCr Then 'Ignore blank paragraphs

    For Each p2 In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
      If p1.Range.Text = p2.Range.Text Then
        DupCount = DupCount + 1
        If p1.Range.Text = p2.Range.Text And DupCount > 1 Then p2.Range.Delete
      End If
    Next p2

  End If

  'Reset Duplicate Counter
    DupCount = 0

Next p1

End Sub
```

However, I would like to know if there is a way to simulate Enter key press in order to create a new paragraph in the place where each duplicate was deleted. In other words, I need to replace the duplicate paragraphs with a new empty paragraph OR to delete the duplicate text without actually removing the paragraph. 
I hope I was clear enough to make you see what I mean. 
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change:

```
p2.Range.Delete
```

to:

```
p2.Range.Text = vbCr
```